# how can I make pop_front with a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

For the assignment I need to make a custom vector class that can be used as the container for a queue where all assignments are O(1).

I'm trying to implement a pop_front function in my vector to do this, but it isn't working.  Here's what I have for it.

```
Void pop_front(){
  arr += sizeof(T);
  siz--;
}
```

`arr` is a dynamically allocated array I'm using for the container, and `siz` is its current size.  Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Comment: [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: @Oli, wouldn't be much of an assignment if it was allowed

Comment: `pop_front` generally returns the value of the first element by the way

Comment: Looks wrong to me, but who can really say without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: @user2758011, you should probably post more code, but trying to implement a queue manually over a vector/array, would probably include some head/tail indices that you don't seem to have here

Comment: @Dgrin91: [No it doesn't ;)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front)

Comment: Could work, just don't try to `delete[] arr`, you need a separate variable with the original address to delete.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I said generally, not always, because [often](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()) [they](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) [do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int))

Comment: @Dgrin91: Sure, but those are different languages.  There are well-established idioms in C++, so the OP should aim to adhere to them.

Comment: @Dgrin91 There's a [good reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600330/pop-back-return-value) `pop*` methods don't return a value.

Comment: @jrok Now that is an actually good reason. Kudos to you.

Comment: sorry, I'd post the rest of the code, but I don't think my instructor would appreciate that very much.  What I was trying to do, is move the pointer for my dynamic array of size n, one space forward, effectively popping off the front, but it won't compile.  I guess c++ doesn't like this.  I think I may need to implement a head and tail as leeor said.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your array container is a class that will contain the size of your included elements. Simply knock off the first element by ignoring it! YOU control how the user accesses each element (through its index) with the `operator[]()` function, so after pop_front(), you change the way the array is accessed, in a way that ignores the first element through `operator[]()`.

Simple enough? Hope so! It needs some work and some testing, but you can do it!

Comment: Thanks, I was considering this, but thought it might be too inefficient memory wise.  Looking at it again, we were only given the the time complexity requirement, nothing in regard to memory.