# How we have a return value of pop() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays

While I was recently studying JS coming from a C++ background, I found out that the pop() function of arrays has a return value in JS.

Now, in C++ we don't have a return value for pop_back() method because according to a paper by Cargill, it is impossible to design an exception-safe stack pop function as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600330/pop-back-return-value)

So how are things working in JS or am I missing something?

Comment: _“So how are things working in JS”_ — This can be answered by the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.pop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the "Exceptions Thrown by T" cases pop up in JavaScript, because there simply is no assignment or construction operator invoked. JavaScript is a garbage-collected language, so everything is a handle to the actual object.
Calling `pop` just shrinks the array by one and returns the handle that was there without doing anything more.

If you want to reason about it in terms of C++, everything is a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, so `pop` just move-constructs that to its return value, which is exception-free.